# Eclipse Debugging:Thread.exit() line not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I try to debug a Java file in eclipse then its finally says "Thread.exit() line not exist"->Edit Source Path . What is this message says.Also there is no method exit in Thread class.Please comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a `Thread.exit()` method in the Sun implementation of Thread.  It is a private method that is called to do some house-keeping before a thread actually exits.

I think you need to fix the source path as the error message suggests.  Make sure that Eclipse is using the correct sources ZIP file for the runtime JAR that you are using.

Comment: Thread.exit() is no where defined in Thread class.Please send me class if you have that onw

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Could you please tell me how to solve it in details?

Comment: @allenwang - It is explained in the Eclipse documentation.  Google can find it for you.  Or if Google is broken ... http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-editsourcelookup.htm

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for your hint. I have read the documentation.But there are many source lookup paths in the default fold. Which one should I choose? Or Should I add a new one? I am a java newbie. Please give me some ideas. I really need your help. (My java is at  /usr/bin/java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `System.exit(0);`.