# Eclipse Debugger: "Thread.exit() line: not available" Error

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm getting the message:

> Thread.exit() line: not available [local variables unavailable]

when my code finishes in debug window.

Running it (without debugging) doesn't throw any error.

The button "Edit Source Lookup Path" appears - I tried adding new lookup path (`jdk1.7.0_25` folder including subfolders) but still getting the same error.

The code is actually very simple -- just array print test for Java practice:

```java
package test2;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        printArray(arr1);
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664328/eclipse-debuggingthread-exit-line-not-exist

Comment: @aquaraga i tried this, i have the jdk and as i said i added the lookup path to the jdk and now also to the jre7 but still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry to ask, but do you have some watch variable setup for debugging. For eg; is there a watch on arr[0] or some variable that is local to printArray(..) method.

Comment: @aquaraga i dont have varibale is watch added, when getting  the error i have (automatically) "this" variable in variable windows :" this Thread  (id=1) " - is the text when i copy the item from variable window.

Comment: I am also facing this problem, and it makes me mad. Do you have any ideas on this problem?