# Thread.exit line: not available. Source not found. Edit source look-up path...?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swing

I am trying to debug my java application and getting Thread.exit line: not available. Source not found. Edit source look-up path...

I am using java 1.6_35 and have jdk installed in my system. I find the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664328/eclipse-debuggingthread-exit-line-not-exist)!

But couldn't able to resolve in my system as i am not able to see any src.zip file in jdk and there is not much information given about what to do to resolve this.

Additionally,In my application two Thread is running 1.Thraed [main] suspended  which is producing this error & 2.Thraed [Thread-3]. This application is a Swing application and i am checking on an issue associated with the second pop-up whick produces some error.

The problem is, In success scenario i am able to debug the 2nd Thread, But in failure case after the Thread.exit() I am not able to proceed, So i couldn't find exactly where the problem occurs?  Please suggest to resolve this... Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is any point in debugging into `Thread.exit` as the problem is highly unlikely to be located there. Maybe it's a native method, and maybe that's why you can't debug it?

Comment: What do you have configured in Eclipse Preferences / Java / Installed JREs? This needs to specify the JDK location to find the source.

Comment: I really haven't this error, maybe you need to reinstall the JDK, also check the JDK env in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but maybe it would be useful for someone:
You can use (for instance right after the end of the loop)

```
System.exit(0);
```

This will stop the thread.